# Updating React and Electron and getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, electron, create-react-app

I have an Electron + React app that I haven't updated in a couple years, originally using these packages:

```
"@rescripts/cli": "^0.0.13",
"@rescripts/rescript-env": "^0.0.11",
"electron": "^7.1.10",
"electron-builder": "^22.3.2",
"react": "^16.12.0",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",
"react-scripts": "3.4.0",
```

And now I want it to use:

```
"@rescripts/cli": "^0.0.13",
"@rescripts/rescript-env": "^0.0.11",
"electron": "^21.1.1",
"electron-builder": "^23.6.0",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
```

When I run my app, the Electron window/menu/etc loads perfectly, but the actual React part of the application doesn't. The code for the React application itself isn't really relevant at this point, because it won't even render a basic "hello world".

I've updated (or commented out) pretty much all of the deprecated features, but I think the webpack part of `rescripts`/Create React App is causing the error, `Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined`.

The `global` variable is nowhere in my code at this point, but my `.webpack.config.js` has:

```
module.exports = config => {
  config.target = "electron-renderer";
  return config;
};
```

and my `.rescriptsrc.js` has:

```
module.exports = [require.resolve("./.webpack.config.js")];
```

And I think these are the culprit, because when I click into the error, it points to compiled webpack files that are not actually in my codebase.

Is there something I missed on the webpack/rescripts side that I need to update? Searching amongst the documentation hasn't been particularly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the `contextIsolation` breaking change in Electron 12 broke the build ([documentation here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/breaking-changes#planned-breaking-api-changes-120)).

By changing the `webPreferences` in my main process file to set `contextIsolation` to false, like the below, everything ran again:

```
webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false
}
```

I do think that @gfnoueira is correct in that I need to take out `rescripts` ultimately as it isn't supported anymore, but to get the app to a "running" state, this did the trick!

Special thanks to [John Lindquist](https://twitter.com/johnlindquist) for pointing out this deprecation!

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is the `rescripts` package. The [repository is archived](https://github.com/harrysolovay/rescripts) and it doesn't support `react-scripts` `v5`, only up until `v4.*`.

If you really want to use `v5`, an option I was considering when I faced this issue was replacing `rescripts` with [`craco`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco). Their `react-scripts v5` support is [still a work in progress](https://github.com/dilanx/craco/issues/426), but for the simple webconfig patching I needed – same thing as you, actually – it worked.

Comment: Ooh thank you! Is there a way to remove the need for `react-scripts` without breaking the whole app?

Comment: @Cassidy I think `vite` is a good alternative to `react-scripts`/CRA (and would make `rescripts/craco`/webpack patching no longer necessary). I've never used it with electron, but I think it wouldn't be that difficult to migrate.